# iOS toast Alert message can't be dismissed in Xamarin.Forms iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using Dependency service in Xamarin.Forms project, and I want to display a toast message in iOS that disappears automatically after 3 seconds. It's an alert that is used in the iOS side, and the message can be displayed, but won't disappear, causing the app to be frozen.

I've tried to disable the animation, but it doesn't help. I have the following codes in iOS project.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MessageIOS))]
namespace DrawRegions.iOS.Services
{
    public class MessageIOS : IMessage
    {
        const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
        const double SHORT_DELAY = 2.0;

        NSTimer alertDelay;
        UIAlertController alert;

        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
        }
        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
        }

        void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
        {
            alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
            {
                dismissMessage();
            });
            alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }

        void dismissMessage()
        {
            if (alert != null)
            {
                alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
            }
            if (alertDelay != null)
            {
                alertDelay.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I call `DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShortAlert("alert message")`, the message will appear, but stays, and the app got stuck.

I've test it on iPhone 6 device and iPhone 6s simulator, both OS version 12.4.

For the Android side, the toast will be displayed and other tasks run simultaneously, and the toast disappears automatically. But of course the Android codes are irrelevant.
Thank you so much if I can have some help.

**Edit：**
I made some changes according to StackOverFlow threads as follows,

```
{
    const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
    const double SHORT_DELAY = 0.75;

    public void LongAlert(string message)
    {
        ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
    }

    public void ShortAlert(string message)
    {
        ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
    }

    void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        var alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, obj =>
        {
            DismissMessage(alert, obj);
        });

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }

    void DismissMessage(UIAlertController alert, NSTimer alertDelay)
    {
        if (alert != null)
        {
            alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
        }

        if (alertDelay != null)
        {
            alertDelay.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the toast will disappear automatically, but once a toast is displayed, all other background task will not be excuted, e.g. I navigate page while displaying a toast, however, the page won't be navigated. But if I remove all codes of displaying these toast, all other codes will be executed.
But on Android, all codes are being executed while toast is displayed and dismissed.

Comment: Did you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the `DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert("alert message");` in Main thread in `Xamarin.forms` Project.

Example:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert("alert message");
    }); 
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());

}
```